# IntelliJ IDEA: Extract Constant in javascript

Tags: intellij-idea, constants

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to extract constants in Java, but for Javascript, esp for React/ES6, I do *not* find the option to extract constant in IntellJ. Also checked the context menu, but it's not there.

I need to change `"CHANGE_HEIGHT"` which is present locally in

```
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_HEIGHT",
      height: height });
}
```

to

```
export const CHANGE_HEIGHT = 'CHANGE_HEIGHT';
```

so I can use it in the reducer.

I do this manually currently, but it would be nice if we can extract it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>. Why is it not there? **How do I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature:( Please follow [WEB-14450](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14450) for updates.

For now I'd suggest using **Extract field** or **Extract variable** refactorings instead